# Cauchy-Schwarz inequality and angle between two vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

[Notes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50SXT.png)

I am reading these notes, and I can't understand the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

It says that it proves that the input is between $[-1,1]$. The Cauchy-Schwarz inequality only states that the product between two vectors divided over the product of their distances is less than $1$ not greater than or equal to $-1$.

For example:

$$ \frac{\langle x,y\rangle}{\|x\|\|y\|}\leq 1.$$

But $ \frac{\langle x,y\rangle}{\|x\|\|y\|}$
could return $-10$ for some values of $x$ and $y$?

Comment: The CS inequality states that the *absolute value* of that expression is at most one. See for example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy–Schwarz_inequality#Statement_of_the_inequality)

Comment: $$ \frac{|\langle x,y\rangle|}{\|x\|\|y\|}\leq 1.$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) states that
$$
|\langle x,y\rangle| \le \Vert x\Vert \cdot \Vert y \Vert
$$
holds for all vectors $x, y$ in an [inner product space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space). Therefore, if both $x$ and $y$ are not zero,
$$
 -1 \le \frac{\langle x,y\rangle}{\Vert x\Vert \cdot \Vert y \Vert} \le 1
$$
and the angle between these vectors can be defined via
$$
 \theta = \arccos \frac{\langle x,y\rangle}{\Vert x\Vert \cdot \Vert y \Vert} \, .
$$

*Remark:* If you “know” the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality only as
$$
\langle x,y\rangle \le \Vert x\Vert \cdot \Vert y \Vert
$$
without the absolute value on the left-hand side then
$$
-\langle x,y\rangle = \langle - x,y\rangle \le \Vert -x\Vert \cdot \Vert y \Vert =  \Vert x\Vert \cdot \Vert y \Vert \\
\implies \langle x,y\rangle \ge - \Vert x\Vert \cdot \Vert y \Vert
$$
gives you the estimate in the other direction.